# Find an example of sets of cosets of different cardinality

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a finite group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Is there an example of $G$ and $H$ such that
$${\rm Card}(\{Hxh\mid h\in H\})\neq{\rm Card}(\{Hyh\mid h\in H\}),$$
where $x,y\in G\setminus H$? Here ${\rm Card}$ means cardinality, namely the number of elements contained in a set, so I wonder if we can find two sets of cosets $\{Hxh\mid h\in H\} $ and $\{Hyh\mid h\in H\}$ such that the number of cosets contained in one set is different from the other one.

Could you give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: If $x \in H$ and $y \in G \setminus H$ the two sets should have different sizes.

Comment: Just so you know, the set $HxH$ is called a double coset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G:=S_5$ and $H:=\{(1),(23),(24),(34),(234),(243)\}\cong S_3$. Set $x:=(35)$ and $y:=(13)(45)$. We have
\begin{align}
&Hx=\{(35),(253),(24)(35),(345),(2534),(2453)\},\\
&Hy=\{(13)(45),(132)(45),(13)(254),(1354),(13542),(13254)\}.
\end{align}
The set of cosets $\{Hxh\mid h\in H\}$ has $3$ elements and they are
\begin{align}
&\{(35),(253),(24)(35),(345),(2534),(2453)\},\\
&\{(235),(25),(2435),(2345),(25)(34),(245)\},\\
&\{(345),(2543),(2354),(45),(254),(23)(45)\};
\end{align}
the set of cosets $\{Hyh\mid h\in H\}$ has $6$ elements and they are
\begin{align}
& \{(13)(45),(132)(45),(13)(254),(1354),(13542),(13254)\},\\
&\{(123)(45),(12)(45),(12543),(12354),(12)(354),(1254)\},\\
&\{(13)(245),(13452),(13)(25),(13524),(1352),(134)(25)\},\\
&\{(1453),(14532),(14253),(14)(35),(142)(35),(14)(253)\},\\
&\{(14523),(1452),(143)(25),(14)(235),(14352),(14)(25)\},\\
&\{(12453),(12)(345),(1253),(124)(35),(12)(35),(12534)\}.
\end{align}

Hence we are done.

Comment: An interpretation of this answer is that cosets may be indexed by where they map $1$ and $5$ to.  So $Hx=(1,3)$ and $Hy=(3,4)$.  Then it is clear that applying $H$ to $(1,3)$ only results in $3$ cosets, as the first co-ordinate is fixed at $1$, whereas $(3,4)$ can map to any of the six ordered pairs of $\{2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 2):

First consider $G=S_3$ and $H=\{e,(1\ 2)\}$, with $x=e$ and $y=(1\ 2\ 3)$. Then
$$
\{Hxh\mid h\in H\} = \{H\} \quad\text{while}\quad \{Hyh\mid h\in H\} = \{H(1\ 2\ 3), H(1\ 2)\}.
$$

But wait, you say, we're not allowed to take $x\in H$? This isn't actually that serious a restriction, since for any nontrivial group $K$ and any $k\in K\setminus\{e\}$, we can now replace $G$ by $G\times K$ and $H$ by $H\times\{e\}$, and $x$ and $y$ by $x\times k$ and $y\times k$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the symmetry group $D_8$ of a square.  Let $C_2$ denote the subgroup fixing a corner $x$ (so $C_2$ consists of the identity, and reflection through the diagonal containing $x$).  Then we can identify the $4$ corners of the square with the cosets of $C_2$. That is all the elements of $C_2g$ map $x$ to $xg$, so we may identify the coset $C_2g$ with the corner $xg$, for each $g\in D_8$.

The orbits of corners under $C_2$ have different sizes: one orbit is the two corners adjacent to $x$, another is the single corner opposite to $x$.

Thus if $a$ is a $90^\circ$ rotation, then $\{C_2ah|h\in C_2\}$ is two cosets, whilst $\{C_2a^2h|h\in C_2\}$ is one.